# C - realloc failure

Tags: c

I have a pointer issue probably but I can't figure out what is the problem with this.
The project is supposed to read numbers from file(Works correctly) and then add the information into a dynamically allocated array.

This is part of the code for reading from the file and adding into the array:
buffer[0] is a special character that marks that the next inputs will be for street array.

I have been looking through the code and changing stuff for about a week and still can't figure out where the problem is.
Note that the first slot works fine, after I realloc for the second time it throws me an exception from inside "AddStreet" saying access violation writing location.
I am sure it is something really stupid that I missed or failed to understand so any help would be appreciated.

Example of the input: # 20 20 30 20 # 40 50 40 60

```
typedef struct street
{
    int start[2];
    int end[2];
}STREET;

void main()
{
int slength=0;
STREET *streets = NULL;
...
ReadFromFile(&streets, people, buildings);
...
}

void ReadFromFile(STREET **pstreets, PERSON *people, BUILDING *buildings)
{
int slength = 0;
...
if(buffer[0] == stre)
    {
        slength += 1;
        *pstreets = (STREET*) realloc(*pstreets, (slength)*sizeof(STREET));
        fscanf(pf, "%d %d %d %d", &a,&b,&c,&d);
        *pstreets = AddStreet(&(*pstreets), slength-1,a,b,c,d);
    }
...
}

STREET* AddStreet(STREET **streets, int length, int bx, int by, int ex, int ey)
{
    if(ValidStreet(bx, by, ex, ey))
    {
        streets[length]->start[0] = bx;
        streets[length]->start[1] = by;
        streets[length]->end[0] = ex;
        streets[length]->end[1] = ey;
    }
    else
    {
        streets[length]->start[0] = ex;
        streets[length]->start[1] = ey;
        streets[length]->end[0] = bx;
        streets[length]->end[1] = by;
    }

return *streets;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried walking through the code with the debugger? In particular, look for writes beyond the end of your arrays.

Comment: Never do **PTR** `= realloc(` **PTR** `, SIZE);` realloc could return `NULL` and then you end up with a memory leak.

Comment: @Sneftel Yeah, I have been going through with the debugger, the realloc doesn't seem to change the size of the array(Same size of 8 without a change) but I think it is because it is only a pointer, unless I am wrong.

Comment: @d3l Yeah, I am aware of it but let's assume that the amount of streets used is not too big that realloc would return NULL.

Comment: Barring a C++ iterator, this: `(&(*pstreets)` is utterly pointless. Now show the type declaration for `STREET`. And since all `AddStreet` does it modify *one* street, you can forego the ptr-to-ptr and length params (and for that matter probably the entire function).

Comment: @user3652113 could you post where the access violation occurs?

Comment: @WhozCraig Added the street struct in the top, sorry about forgetting that one. I changed the `(&(*pstreets)` into pstreets before and now as well but it still gives the same error.

Comment: And the **full** body of `AddStreet`. Your current post omits the return (and there *better* be a `return`).

Comment: @d3l The error happens in the 2nd entrance to AddStreet, at the line of `streets[length]->start[0] = bx;`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry, failed to copy. Added now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dereference logic for AddStreet is wrong. You're dereferencing `length` from a pointer to pointer base. You want to dereference from the pointer it points to to get the actual street object.

When `streets` is `STREET**`, then this:

```
streets[length]->start[0]
```

says "get me the pointer in the array of pointers starting at `streets` at offset `length`, then dereference that pointer". But your array isn't an array of pointers. In fact, there is only *one* pointer (and you happen to pass it by address).

This will do what you want:

```
STREET* AddStreet(STREET **streets, int length, int bx, int by, int ex, int ey)
{
    if(ValidStreet(bx, by, ex, ey))
    {
        (*streets)[length].start[0] = bx;
        (*streets)[length].start[1] = by;
        (*streets)[length].end[0] = ex;
        (*streets)[length].end[1] = ey;
    }
    else
    {
        (*streets)[length].start[0] = ex;
        (*streets)[length].start[1] = ey;
        (*streets)[length].end[0] = bx;
        (*streets)[length].end[1] = by;
    }

    return *streets;
}
```

---

Frankly, you shouldn't be passing the pointer to pointer in the first place.

```
void AddStreet(STREET* street, int bx, int by, int ex, int ey)
{
    if(ValidStreet(bx, by, ex, ey))
    {
        street->start[0] = bx;
        street->start[1] = by;
        street->end[0] = ex;
        street->end[1] = ey;
    }
    else
    {
        street->start[0] = ex;
        street->start[1] = ey;
        street->end[0] = bx;
        street->end[1] = by;
    }
}
```

invoked as this:

```
    fscanf(pf, "%d %d %d %d", &a,&b,&c,&d);
    AddStreet(*pstreets + (slength-1), a,b,c,d);
```

would work and is considerably less prone to error.

Comment: Wow, amazing. Thanks a lot. I kept thinking the problem is with the allocation.

Comment: @user3652113 oh there are plenty of problems there too. The cast is not warranted ([**read this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), it applies to `realloc` as well), and as mentioned by d3l, you should validate realloc didn't return NULL. But this should get you going. glad it helped.

Comment: For some reason on the void version gives an error saying the expression must have class type (The "street" in every "street." line). Never seen that error before.

Comment: @user3652113 You mean the second version I posted ? Ah. ok. yeah, it was broken. updated. sry.